# Can't use search feature in datatables server-side processing with django-datatables-view

Tags: python, django, view, datatable, server-side

I want to implement [datatables with server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) because I have a lot of data to present in a single page(simple datatables are taking a lot of time).I went through the documentation in [django-datatables-view](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view)

I tried to implement it in my project,I can now successfully retrieve data from the server side but cannot use '**search**' feature.

If I type some thing in searchbox,it showing processing for a while but not updating the list of data displayed in the tables.

I used python 3.6.5 and Django 2.0.6

Below is the code which I used:

html :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var a = $('#tl').dataTable( {
      "bPaginate": true,
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "{% url 'order_list_json' %}"
    });
  });
  </script>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from .import views
from .views import OrderListJson

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    .
    .
    .
    .
    url(r'^tabledata/$',OrderListJson.as_view(), name='order_list_json')
]

#used to access files in static folder using url 'static/'
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

views.py:

```
from django_datatables_view.base_datatable_view import BaseDatatableView

.
.
.
.
.

class OrderListJson(BaseDatatableView):
    model  = Network1
    columns = ['barcode', 'volret', 'state', 'flags', 'capacity','typefull','ip']
    order_columns = ['barcode', 'volret', 'state', 'flags', 'capacity','typefull','ip']
    max_display_length = 100


    def get_initial_queryset(self):
        return Network1.objects.filter(barcode__in=Masterlist.objects.values('barcode'))

    def render_column(self, row, column):
        return super(OrderListJson, self).render_column(row, column)

    def filter_queryset(self, qs):

        search = self.request.GET.get(u'search[value]', None)
        if search:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=search)

        return qs
```

can anyone please help me to implement the search feature?

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is here:

`qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=search)`

`name` should be the name of the column you want to search :

`['barcode', 'volret', 'state', 'flags', 'capacity','typefull','ip']`